# How to parse a speciffic strings from multiple files with shell script

Tags: shell-script, embedded, debugging

I am developing an esp32 project and I log all the esp32 uart debug output in multiple files. At some point my early releases crash and the output looks something like this:

> Guru Meditation Error: Core  0 panic'ed (Cache disabled but cached memory region accessed).
>
> Core  0 register dump:
> PC      : 0x40008150  PS      : 0x00060034  A0      : 0x8008225c  A1      : 0x3ffb0670
> A2      : 0x3f40117c  A3      : 0x00000000  A4      : 0x00000004  A5      : 0x00000000
> A6      : 0x00000000  A7      : 0xfffffff7  A8      : 0x00000000  A9      : 0x00000000
> A10     : 0x000000ad  A11     : 0x00000000  A12     : 0x800861de  A13     : 0x3ffbb010
> A14     : 0x00000003  A15     : 0x00060a23  SAR     : 0x00000020  EXCCAUSE: 0x00000007
> EXCVADDR: 0x00000000  LBEG    : 0x4000c2e0  LEND    : 0x4000c2f6  LCOUNT  : 0x00000000
> Core  0 was running in ISR context:
> EPC1    : 0x4008a2e8  EPC2    : 0x00000000  EPC3    : 0x00000000  EPC4    : 0x40008150
>
> Backtrace:0x4000814d:0x3ffb0670 0x40082259:0x3ffb0700 0x400833b9:0x3ffb0720 0x400833e2:0x3ffb0740 0x40081e6a:0x3ffb0760 0x4008a2e5:0x3ffbb0a0 0x4008438d:0x3ffbb0c0 0x400830ed:0x3ffbb0e0 0x40083271:0x3ffbb110 0x400de4b1:0x3ffbb130 0x400dd525:0x3ffbb150 0x400dd7c5:0x3ffbb170 0x400de175:0x3ffbb1d0 0x400dccf2:0x3ffbb240 0x400dcedf:0x3ffbb2a0 0x400dcf47:0x3ffbb2d0 0x400dbebf:0x3ffbb2f0 0x400dbed2:0x3ffbb310 0x400d757a:0x3ffbb330 0x400d770a:0x3ffbb360 0x400d3a66:0x3ffbb380
>
> ELF file SHA256: c278c3c874dd3748
>
> Rebooting...

At this point I can start to review my code at the points where the backtrace is pointing:

```
addr2line xtensa-esp32- -pfiaC -e project.elf 0x400d3a66 0x400d770a 0x400d757a ...(the remaining addresses of the backtrace)
```

the output looks like:

> 0x400d3a66: root_task at $somePATH/build/../main/main.c:163
>
> 0x400d770a: init at $somePATH/build/../main/init_app.c:122
>
> 0x400d757a: init_nvs_app at $somePATH/build/../main/init_app.c:47
>
> (inlined by) init_nvs_app at /$somePATH/build/../main/init_app.c:34

This is tedious. So I need to automate it, but I don't have much experience with shell scripts(new to linux)

Also there are million different ways to approach it. Could someone experienced help me out to grep the text between "Guru Meditation Error:" and "Rebooting..." and what's the best way to separate the PC(program counter) addresses from the Backtrace into a single line ignoring the SP(stack pointer) ones(SP addresses start with 0x3ff in this speciffic case).
I have tried some things with grep regular expressions and awk but cannot nail it good enough.

Comment: what have you tried?  please edit your question and add your awk script.   BTW, this looks like a job that would not be fun or easy to do with sh + simple tools like grep or sed, it does require something more capable, like awk or perl....so using awk was a good decision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sed` version:

```
sed -n -E -e '/^Backtrace:/ {s/Backtrace://; s/:0x3ff[^ ]* */ /g; p}' input.txt
```

This ignores all lines that don't start with "Backtrace:" and uses two search & replace rules to modify matching lines before printing them out.

The `s/:0x3ff[^ ]* */ /g` operation matches any text beginning with `:0x3ff` followed by zero-or-more non-space characters (`[^ ]*`), followed by zero-or-more spaces ( `*`), and replaces any matches found with a single space character.  It is a global search and replace (`/g`), so will affect **all** matches found on the line, not just the first match.

It does not attempt to limit its action to only lines between "Guru Meditation" and "Rebooting".   This should be adequate if there aren't any other lines beginning with "Backtrace:" in the input, or if you only feed it one input file at a time.

If the `0x3ff` isn't constant across multiple runs, it can be changed to a regexp that matches a colon followed by `0x` followed by 1 or more hex digits.  e.g.

```
s/:0x[0-9a-f]+//gi
```

This change can also be used with the awk and perl versions below if necessary.

`awk` version:

```
awk -v SKIP=1 '/^Guru Meditation Error/ { SKIP=0 };
               /^Rebooting\.\.\./ { SKIP=1} ;
               SKIP==1 || ! /^Backtrace:/ { next };
               {
                   sub("^Backtrace:","");
                   gsub(":0x3ff[^ ]* *"," ");
                   print
               }
              ' input.txt
```

This skips all input that isn't between the "Guru Meditation" and "Rebooting" lines, as well as all input that doesn't begin with "Backtrace:".  Then it modifies non-skipped lines with two search and replace operations (`sub()` and `gsub()`) before printing out the modified line.

perl version:

```
perl -lne 'BEGIN {$SKIP=1};
           $SKIP=0 if (m/^Guru Meditation Error/);
           $SKIP=1 if (m/^Rebooting\.\.\./);
           next if ($SKIP || ! m/^Backtrace:/);
           s/Backtrace://;
           s/:0x3ff\H*\h*/ /g;
           print' input.txt
```

This works like the awk version, but the code looks like a cross between the awk and sed versions (perl is capable of both awk-like and sed-like syntax...and a whole lot more).

The final `s//g` operation has been modified to use perl's `\H` (non- horizontal space character) and `\h` (horizontal space character) matches instead of just spaces (i.e. tabs and spaces and more - see `man perlrecharclass` and search for the section on "Whitespace" for details)

Output for all three versions is identical:

```
0x4000814d 0x40082259 0x400833b9 0x400833e2 0x40081e6a 0x4008a2e5 0x4008438d 0x400830ed 0x40083271 0x400de4b1 0x400dd525 0x400dd7c5 0x400de175 0x400dccf2 0x400dcedf 0x400dcf47 0x400dbebf 0x400dbed2 0x400d757a 0x400d770a 0x400d3a66
```

All three versions are capable of taking input from stdin or from one or more filename(s) on the command line. The examples above use `input.txt` (which is a text file I copy-pasted your sample input into).

They all output to stdout, so can be used for command substitution.  e.g.

```
addr2line xtensa-esp32- -pfiaC -e project.elf $(sed -n -E -e '/^Backtrace:/ {s/Backtrace://; s/:0x3ff[^ ]* */ /g; p}' input.txt)
```

Comment: Thanks for the exceptional reply! I have been busy so I couldn't edit my question to add the things I have tried.